# ImportError: No module named _grabscreen (PIL)

Tags: python, screenshot, python-imaging-library, importerror

I am trying to use PIL to get screenshot, but some import error appear when I import ImageGrab from PIL. (Platforms are Mac OS X and Debian)

like,

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
```

When I do this, the result is

```
File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/ImageGrab.py", line 34, in <module>
import _grabscreen
ImportError: No module named _grabscreen
```

This said that there is no module named "_grabscreen".

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: AFAIK `_grabscreen` is available only on Windows, but wait for a definitive answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mac OS support has since been added to Pillow ImageGrab, as of version 3.0.0. It uses the same API as on Windows -

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
im = ImageGrab.grab()  # entire screen
im2 = ImageGrab.grab([0, 0, 100, 100])  # a selected region of the screen
```

However, there is no Linux support at the moment.

You can read more here - http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.2.x/reference/ImageGrab.html